# Github create comment api not working

Tags: github, github-api

I'm looking at the github create comment API referenced here - https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/comments/#create-a-comment

As per the API, if I do a GET at https://api.github.com/repos/govin/log4js-node/pulls/1/comments, I get an array of comments back.

However, when I do a POST at https://api.github.com/repos/govin/log4js-node/pulls/1/comments, the response is 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that:

- a POST would require a proper authentication, as shown in this [GitHub POST tutorial](https://gist.github.com/caspyin/2288960#post).
  No authentication means 404.

  ```
  curl --user "caspyin" --request POST --data {...}
  ```
- you need to proper data mentioned in "[Create a comment](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/comments/#create-a-comment)"

  ```
  {
    "body": "Nice change",
    "commit_id": "6dcb09b5b57875f334f61aebed695e2e4193db5e",
    "path": "file1.txt",
    "position": 4
  }
  ```